# Problems with jQuery .resize handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, which only allows a set of jQuery hover functions to execute when the window width is above 760 px.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

function checkWidth(){
var windowWidth= jQuery(window).width();
if(windowWidth >= 760){
    jQuery('.wsite-menu-item-wrap').hover(
    function(){
    jQuery(this).children(".wsite-menu-wrap").addClass('hover');
    }, function(){
    jQuery(this).children(".wsite-menu-wrap").removeClass('hover');
    });//End Hover
    jQuery('.wsite-menu-subitem-wrap').hover(
    function(){
    jQuery(this).children(".wsite-menu-wrap").addClass('subitem-hover');
    }, function(){
    jQuery(this).children(".wsite-menu-wrap").removeClass('subitem-hover');
    });//End Hover
    }//EndIf
    }
checkWidth();
jQuery(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

I'm encountering an interesting bug: when I load the page at a width BELOW 760px and resize to above 760, it works as planned: the hover code doesn't execute under 760 and starts to execute above 760. But if I do it the other way around- load above 760 and then resize to a smaller window, the hover code continues to execute even after I've resized the window to below 760. Any ideas as to why this might be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you do it backwards, the statement

```
if(windowWidth >= 760)
```

will be false, before it was true.. right? so it added classes and everything, so you need and else statement for an example to change the classes back

if its small at first, the statment will be false, if you rezise it the statment will be true and the classes will be changed

Comment: I would think that since I added jQuery(window).resize(checkWidth); at the bottom, it would change back to false again once I run below 760, since the code is execute every time the window is resized.